# array_walk returns true or false. Need to return a variable instead

Tags: php, arrays

Badly stuck here : I have to compare first two values of the string and return the third part of the string.
eg if(80 < 88 && 88 < 96) return 1000. Currently since i am using array_walk i am just getting true or false.   Any other work around for this apart from doing multiple foreach ?

```
 $fortuneArray = ['1'=> '80 | 96 | 1000','2'=>'3648|4000|100'];
$valueToBeCompared = ['88'];

$val =array_walk($fortuneArray,'test_print',$valueToBeCompared);

function test_print($fortuneArray,$valueToBeCompared)
{
   $compare = explode('|',$fortuneArray);

   if($compare[0] < $valueToBeCompared && $compare[1] > $valueToBeCompared){

              return  $compare[2];
            }
        }
```

Comment: What should be the expected result of `$compare[2];`  1000?

Answer (score 3):

By the syntax,

```
bool array_walk ( array &$array , callable $callback [, mixed $userdata = NULL ] )
```

It will return boolean value i.e. either true or false.

If you want to achieve something like fetching value from it, you can pass a variable by address, so relative value will be stored in that variable.

Here is example,

```
$fortuneArray      = ['1' => '80 | 96 | 1000', '2' => '3648|4000|100'];
$valueToBeCompared = 88;
$result = '';
array_walk($fortuneArray, function ($fortuneArray, $key, $valueToBeCompared) use (&$result)
{
    $compare = explode(' | ', $fortuneArray);
    if ($compare[0] < $valueToBeCompared && $compare[1] > $valueToBeCompared) {
        $result = $compare[2];
    }
}, $valueToBeCompared);
echo $result;
```

I think `$result` is what you require.

Demo [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f026f3d607d706e61354d287734146ca8a71a507).

Answer (score 2):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/774667)

```
<?php

$fortuneArray = ['1' => '80 | 96 | 1000', '2' => '3648|4000|100'];
$valueToBeCompared = ['88'];
//1. here you are passing an array so while comparison use its zero index
//2. This is the third parameter passed in callback not second
$result="";
$val = array_walk(
        $fortuneArray, 
        function ($fortuneArray, $key,$valueToBeCompared) use (&$result)
        {
            $compare = explode('|', $fortuneArray);
            $compare=array_map("trim",$compare);//each value should be trimmed from spaces
            if ($compare[0] < $valueToBeCompared[0] && $compare[1] > $valueToBeCompared[0])
            {
               $result = $compare[2];
            }
        }, $valueToBeCompared);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**
`1000`

Answer (score 1):

Using a functional iterator is ill-advised for this task.  Using a `break`able loop will offer best performance because as soon as a qualifying dataset is encountered, there is no point in iterating further.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UOd3W))

```
$fortuneArray = [
    '1' => '80 | 96 | 1000',
    '2' => '3648|4000|100'
];
$valueToBeCompared = ['88'];

$result = null;
foreach ($fortuneArray as $dataset) {
    [$min, $max, $fortune] = explode('|', $dataset);
    if ((int)$min < $valueToBeCompared[0] && $valueToBeCompared[0] < (int)$max) {
        $result = (int)$fortune;
        break;
    }
}
echo $result;  // 1000
```

Some notes:

- You should normalize your `$fortuneArray` syntax to remove the whotespace characters.  Until then I am removing the whitespace by casting the exploded values as integers.
- `$valueToBeCompared` should be a scalar value.  There is no benefit to declaring it as an array.
- Writing your script to avoid unnecessary iterations is a clear indication that a programmer knows what they are doing.  Even if the performance boost is unnoticeable, it is simply best practice.  Whatever technique you chose to use, it should include `break` or `return` as part of a loop halting process.